# Twitter Bootstrap - How to build form in resized browzer window?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap framework and I'm trying to build subscribe form.

```
<div style="text-align: center; margin: 35px auto;">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="input-large" id="" name="" placeholder="your@email.com">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large" style="background-color: #88d0b0; color: white;
            border: 0;">
            Subscribe</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

I need to make my text input more higher(like button), so my CSS:

```
input.input-large[class=input-large] {
padding: 11px 19px;
font-size: 17.5px;
}
```

When browzer window is maximized, subscribe form looks good.
[image]

But when I'm trying to resize my screen it looks like:
[image]

In my project I'm using CSS:bootstrap.min.css and JS:bootstrap.min.js. Also my project has following construction:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
....
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container"> ..My subscribe form... </div>
</body>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why this: `input.input-large[class=input-large]`

Comment: Try using the the `.form-inline` on your form element.

Comment: Unfortunately with class .form-inline the same result.

Comment: You could also try wrapping your two input and button in a `<div class="input-append">` div [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/qp2WE/)

Comment: Based on your screen shots it looks like there might be a media query at work.  `.input-large` has a set width of `210px` so your input should not re-size like it does in your screenshot.  Are you sure you're not using `bootstrap-responsive.css` or `bootstrap-responsive.min.css`?  The order that you include your stylesheets will also affect the final outcome.  Do you have a link to the page?

Comment: @hungerstar you are absolutely right! The problem was in my `.input-large` class for the text input and media queries. I'm using `bootstrap-responsive.min.css` and this class has a set width of `210px` when my screen becomes <= 767px (media query works). But I was using this class not to make my form wider, only to make it higher. So, by renaming this class like `input-large-height` I solved my problem. Now media query isn't change width of form when I'm resizing my browzer screen and input and button leaves on the same line with a same height.

Comment: I will move my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screen shots it looks like there might be a media query at work. `.input-large` has a set width of `210px` so your input should not re-size like it does in your screenshot. Are you sure you're not using `bootstrap-responsive.css` or `bootstrap-responsive.min.css`? The order that you include your stylesheets will also affect the final outcome. Do you have a link to the page?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because when you shrink the window, there isn't enough space to fit both elements on the same line, so the `button` is moved down to the next line.

The way you can fix this is by implementing responsive design. This is done with media queries and different css stylesheets to create a different layout when the screen size changes. Alternatively, you can include `bootstrap.responsive.css` in your `head` and see if you like the look that gives you.  Here's some information on responsive design: 
http://tuftsdev.github.io/WebProgramming/lecture_notes/css3.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries